# Getting an "Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error" while using Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

When I run the command `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace` on Windows 10 I get the following error:

> Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 8): Syntax Error in 'for loop' - Valid syntax: for [item] in [collection] in 2018-09-14-Rendering a python dict in jinja2.markdown
> jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  Liquid syntax error (line 8): Syntax Error in 'for loop' - Valid syntax: for [item] in [collection]

Does anyone know how to fix that problem?

---

The file **2018-09-14-Rendering a python dict in jinja2.markdown** content is:

````
---
layout: post
title:  "Rendering a python dict in jinja2"
date:   2018-09-14 00:01:57 +0800
categories: python jinja2
---

    ```python
    url_list = [{'target': 'http://10.58.48.103:5000/', 'clicks': '1'}, 
                {'target': 'http://slash.org', 'clicks': '4'},
                {'target': 'http://10.58.48.58:5000/', 'clicks': '1'},
                {'target': 'http://de.com/a', 'clicks': '0'}]
    #Python 2.7
    
    {% for key, value in url_list.iteritems() %}
        <li>{{ value["target"] }}</li> 
    {% endfor %}
    #Python 3
    
    {% for key, value in url_list.items() %}
        <li>{{ value["target"] }}</li> 
    {% endfor %}
    ```
````

Comment: What did you change from the last working version? any code to post? There seems to be a problem with the file `2018-09-14-...` or the layout it uses.

Comment: @marcanuy Thank you for your fast reply.  I modify my post and append the content of 2018-09-14-Rendering a python dict in jinja2.markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - The `{% raw %}` tag is part of the solution for you python code in [this post](https://github.com/perrot/perrot.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2018-09-14-Rendering%20a%20python%20dict%20in%20jinja2.markdown) and [this post](https://github.com/perrot/perrot.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2018-09-14-list%20of%20dictionary%20in%20jinja2.markdown).

2 - The other part of the solution [can be a bug in the way Jekyll manages excerpts](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/7248).

Remove empty lines in your code, and it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I upgrade Jekyll to the latest version 3.7.4 with the command "bundle update" and leave an empty line between highlight and raw. But it still has an error " Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 3): 'highlight' tag was never closed". The bug was fixed in v3.8.x. I don't know how to upgrade my Jekyll to the version 3.8.x.

Comment: Sorry, the space between highlight and raw is a fix in 3.8.x. The only solution for you, as you have to stick to gh pages, is to remove empty line in your code. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Liquid tries to process your source code, particularly the jinja2 control tags, for that you need to tell Liquid to avoid processing it with the `raw` tags:

```
{% highlight python %}
{% raw %}
   url_list = [{'target': 'http://10.58.48.103:5000/', 'clicks': '1'}, 
                {'target': 'http://slash.org', 'clicks': '4'},
                {'target': 'http://10.58.48.58:5000/', 'clicks': '1'},
                {'target': 'http://de.com/a', 'clicks': '0'}]
    #Python 2.7

    {% for key, value in url_list.iteritems() %}
        <li>{{ value["target"] }}</li> 
    {% endfor %}
    #Python 3

    {% for key, value in url_list.items() %}
        <li>{{ value["target"] }}</li> 
    {% endfor %}

{% endraw %}
{% endhighlight %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I got another error messages:   Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 2): 'raw' tag was never closed in D:/MyPorfolio/perrot.github.io/_posts/2018-09-14-Rendering a python dict in jinja2.markdown/#excerpt
  Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (D:/MyPorfolio/perrot.github.io/_includes/head.html line 2): 'raw' tag was never closed included in /_layouts/default.html
jekyll 3.7.3 | Error:  Liquid syntax error (D:/MyPorfolio/perrot.github.io/_includes/head.html line 2): 'raw' tag was never closed included

Comment: Did you include endraw?

Comment: Yes, I just replace the content of _.markdown with your post. It includes a endraw tag.